# Why Does This IQueryable.Where<TSource> Call Return a Different Type Than IQueryable<TSource>?

Tags: c#, generics, linq-to-sql, iqueryable

This is going to be somewhat difficult to explain and provide code examples for, so bear with me and please ask questions if I'm not clear.

### Explanation

I have a situation where I pass an `IQueryable<T>` (using LINQ-to-SQL) into a generic method, and then call a `.Where` on a copy of the `IQueryable`. The generic method can be called by either of two different code paths. In one of these code paths, the `.ElementType` of the `IQueryable` changes after the `Where` call, but in the other it stays the same. I'm getting errors in the case where it changes, and I need it to not do that.

### Code

I have a type called `InventoryGridQueryElement`, which inherits from `PivotGridQueryElement`, along these lines:

```
public class InventoryGridQueryElement : PivotGridQueryElement {

    public int IId { get; set; }

    ... other simple public properties
}
```

Another class creates an `IQueryable<InventoryGridQueryElement>`. In one execution path, the one that is creating problems, this object is saved in an `Object` variable, and then that variable is passed into the generic method. In the other execution path, the variable that is passed into the generic method is still an `IQueryable<InventoryGridQueryElement>`.

Both execution paths first call this method, with the `IQueryable<InventoryGridQueryElement>` ( or `Object`) being passed in as the `dataSource` parameter:

```
protected DataTableAndPaging FilterDataSource<T>( IQueryable<T> dataSource, NameValueCollection queryString ) where T : PivotGridQueryElement {
```

which then calls

```
iqueryable = iqueryable.FilterByQueryString( this, queryString );
```

i.e.

```
public static IQueryable<T> FilterByQueryString<T>( this IQueryable<T> iQ, Grid grid, NameValueCollection query ) where T : PivotGridQueryElement {
```

which includes these two lines

```
var copy = iQ;

...

copy = copy.Where( pgr1 => iQ.Where( pgr2 => pgr2.Key == pgr1.Key && pgr2.DataField == column.DataField && pgr2.ColumnText.Contains( requestValue ) ).Any() );
```

### Actual Problem

The second of those two lines, with `copy.Where`, is where the problem occurs. In the problematic execution path, if I set a watch on `copy.ElementType`, then before executing this line I have

```
+       copy.ElementType    {Name = "InventoryGridQueryElement" FullName = "ProjectNamespace.Models.GridModelInventory+InventoryGridQueryElement"}  System.Type {System.RuntimeType}
```

but then after stepping over the line I have

```
+       copy.ElementType    {Name = "PivotGridQueryElement" FullName = "ProjectNamespace.Models.PivotGridQueryElement"} System.Type {System.RuntimeType}
```

In the other execution path, where everything works, I have the first watch result both before and after executing the `copy.Where` line.

Once the query is actually made, an error is thrown because the query involves the `.IId` property of `InventoryGridQueryElement`, but `PivotGridQueryElement` has no such property.

*Update:*

I decided to try a different method to track the type of `T` rather than watching `IQueryable.ElementType`. I switched to the Locals window and looked at the type listed for each of copy and iQ. Both iQ and copy are listed as `IQueryable<PivotGridQueryElement>` in the problem path, even though iQ.ElementType and copy.ElementType are both `InventoryGridQueryElement`. In the successful path, they are both listed as `IQueryable<InventoryGridQueryElement>`.

I then added these lines before and after the query:

```
Type copyType1 = copy.GetType().GetGenericArguments()[ 0 ];
Type elementType1 = copy.ElementType;

copy = copy.Where( pgr1 => iQ.Where( pgr2 => pgr2.Key == pgr1.Key && pgr2.DataField == column.DataField && pgr2.ColumnText.Contains( requestValue ) ).Any() );

Type copyType2 = copy.GetType().GetGenericArguments()[ 0 ];
Type elementType2 = copy.ElementType;
```

In the good path, `copyType1` == `elementType1` == `copyType2` == `elememtType2` == `InventoryGridQueryElement`.

In the bad path, `copyType1` == `elementType1` == `InventoryGridQueryElement`, but `copyType2` == `elementType2` == `PivotGridQueryElement`.

*Update Again:*

I wrote a short standalone console program to reproduce the problem. I asked [a new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25778701/why-does-this-queryable-where-call-change-the-queryables-type-parameter) referring to only that example without this question's additional concerns about the complex `.Where` query or LINQ-to-SQL.

### Question

So, for what possible reasons might a `.Where` call change the `ElementType` of the `IQueryable`? Do any of those reasons appear to be related to my specific scenario?

Note: This code is tightly coupled with a third-party API we're using. I don't like the way that API is written, and it's only because of it that this queryable is ever stored in a generic object.

Comment: In the execution path that has the problem, what is `T` when you get to that line?  I was able to cause the same behavior if `T` is interpreted as `PivotGridQueryElement` when the `.Where` is evaluated.  In fact, here is a simple one-line demonstration: `var iQ2 = ((IQueryable<PivotGridQueryElement>)iQ).Select(s => s)` will now evaluate `ElementType` as `PivotGridQueryElement` -- but I'm not so sure why.

Comment: @mellamokb It's InventoryGridQueryElement in both paths until that line, and then it switches in one of them. In your example you used `Queryable.Select<TSource, TResult>`, which returns `IQueryable<TResult>`, which may or may not be the same type as `IQueryable<TSource>`, so I'm less surprised than when `Queryable.Where<TSource>` returns an `IQueryable<TSource>` that is a different type than `IQueryable<TSource>`.

Comment: @mellamokb Jon Skeet gave me a [good answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25778788/2449863) to my related question.