# Why Does This Queryable.Where Call Change the Queryable's Type Parameter?

Tags: c#, linq, types, iqueryable

### Code to Reproduce Issue

I ran into a situation where an `IQueryable.Where<TSource>` call was returning an `IQueryable<TOther>` where `TOther != TSource`. I put together some sample code to reproduce it:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace IQueryableWhereTypeChange {
    class Program {
        static void Main( string[] args ) {
            var ints = new List<ChildQueryElement>();

            for( int i = 0; i < 10; i++ ) {
                ints.Add( new ChildQueryElement() { Num = i, Value = i.ToString() } );
            }

            IQueryable<ChildQueryElement> theIQ = ints.AsQueryable();

            Object theObj = theIQ;

            Type theObjElementType = ( (IQueryable<ParentQueryElement>) theObj ).ElementType;
            Type theObjGenericType = ( (IQueryable<ParentQueryElement>) theObj ).GetType().GetGenericArguments()[ 0 ];

            var iQ = ( (IQueryable<ParentQueryElement>) theObj );

            var copy = iQ;

            Type copyType1 = copy.GetType().GetGenericArguments()[ 0 ];
            Type elementType1 = copy.ElementType;

            copy = copy.Where( qe1 => true );

            Type copyType2 = copy.GetType().GetGenericArguments()[ 0 ];
            Type elementType2 = copy.ElementType;

            Console.WriteLine( "theObjElementType : " + theObjElementType.ToString() );
            Console.WriteLine( "theObjGenericType : " + theObjGenericType.ToString() );
            Console.WriteLine( "copyType1 : " + copyType1.ToString() );
            Console.WriteLine( "elementType1 : " + elementType1.ToString() );
            Console.WriteLine( "copyType2 : " + copyType2.ToString() );
            Console.WriteLine( "elementType2 : " + elementType2.ToString() );
        }
    }

    public class ParentQueryElement {
        public int Num { get; set; }
    }
    public class ChildQueryElement : ParentQueryElement {
        public string Value { get; set; }
    }
}
```

The output of this program is:

```
theObjElementType : IQueryableWhereTypeChange.ChildQueryElement    
theObjGenericType : IQueryableWhereTypeChange.ChildQueryElement    
copyType1 : IQueryableWhereTypeChange.ChildQueryElement  
elementType1 : IQueryableWhereTypeChange.ChildQueryElement  
copyType2 : IQueryableWhereTypeChange.ParentQueryElement  
elementType2 : IQueryableWhereTypeChange.ParentQueryElement
```

### Summary of Code Results

So, we store an `IQueryable<ChildQueryElement>` in an `Object`, then cast the object to `IQueryable<ParentQueryElement>`, where the child type inherits from the parent type. At this point the object stored in the `Object` variable still knows it is a collection of the child type. We then call `Queryable.Where` on it, but the object that is returned is no longer aware that it contains the child type, and thinks it only contains the parent type.

### Question

Why does this happen? Is there any way I can avoid this, other than skipping the step where it gets stored in an object? I ask this because I'm dealing with a third-party API that demands I pass it an `Object`, and I don't want to have to rewrite a bunch of third-party code.

### Updated Sample Code

After getting some advice from Jon Skeet, I tried this sample code, which uses a dynamic variable for copy. Replace the body of `Main` with the following:

```
var ints = new List<ChildQueryElement>();

for( int i = 0; i < 10; i++ ) {
    ints.Add( new ChildQueryElement() { Num = i, Value = i.ToString() } );
}

IQueryable<ChildQueryElement> theIQ = ints.AsQueryable();

Object theObj = theIQ;

Type theObjElementType = ( (IQueryable<ParentQueryElement>) theObj ).ElementType;
Type theObjGenericType = ( (IQueryable<ParentQueryElement>) theObj ).GetType().GetGenericArguments()[ 0 ];

var iQ = ( (IQueryable<ParentQueryElement>) theObj );

dynamic copy = iQ;

Type copyType1 = copy.GetType().GetGenericArguments()[ 0 ];
Type elementType1 = ((IQueryable)copy).ElementType;

Expression<Func<ParentQueryElement, bool>> del = qe => true;

copy = Queryable.Where( copy, del );

Type copyType2 = copy.GetType().GetGenericArguments()[ 0 ];
Type elementType2 = ((IQueryable)copy).ElementType;

Console.WriteLine( "theObjElementType : " + theObjElementType.ToString() );
Console.WriteLine( "theObjGenericType : " + theObjGenericType.ToString() );
Console.WriteLine( "copyType1 : " + copyType1.ToString() );
Console.WriteLine( "elementType1 : " + elementType1.ToString() );
Console.WriteLine( "copyType2 : " + copyType2.ToString() );
Console.WriteLine( "elementType2 : " + elementType2.ToString() );
```

Unfortunately, the output remains the same.

Comment: It's a little bit sensitive for newer users, I guess.  Highlighting non-code as code is idiotic.  Here, have an edit.

Comment: @Will Thank you Will. How did you do that? Did it just not give you the warning? Because if so, then that answers my meta question.

Comment: No, it doesn't check after a certain rep threshold.  Not sure what that is.  Alternatively, you can turn off the syntax highlighting for selected code blocks (search on [meta.se] for details), or just mark it as code and leave a comment asking for help editing underneath your q/a :/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Why does this happen?

Because the `Where` call is receiving a type argument of `ParentQueryElement` as `TSource`. It creates a result based on `TSource` as a new object... so you end up with something which "knows" about `ParentQueryElement` instead of `ChildQueryElement`.

It's easy enough to demonstrate this without going into LINQ at all:

```
using System;

public interface IWrapper<out T>
{
    T Value { get; }
}

public class Wrapper<T> : IWrapper<T>
{
    private readonly T value;

    public Wrapper(T value)
    {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public T Value { get { return value; } }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        IWrapper<string> original = new Wrapper<string>("foo");
        IWrapper<object> original2 = original;        
        IWrapper<object> rewrapped = Rewrap(original2);

        Console.WriteLine(original2.GetType()); // Wrapper<string>
        Console.WriteLine(rewrapped.GetType()); // Wrapper<object>
    }

    static IWrapper<T> Rewrap<T>(IWrapper<T> wrapper)
    {
        return new Wrapper<T>(wrapper.Value);
    }    
}
```

> Is there any way I can avoid this, other than skipping the step where it gets stored in an object?

Well, you could call `Where` dynamically, at which point the type argument will be inferred at execution time instead:

```
dynamic copy = ...;

Expression<Func<ChildQueryElement, bool>> filter = qe1 => true;
// Can't call an extension method "on" dynamic; call it statically instead
copy = Queryable.Where(copy, filter);
```

Note that the expression tree type needs to be `Func<ChildQueryElement, bool>` as well... it's not clear to me whether that would be a problem for you.

Comment: Thanks for the help Mr. Skeet. I'm not familiar with the `Queryable.Where` syntax you proposed at the end of your answer. I tried doing this: dynamic copy = iQ; Expression<Func<ParentQueryElement, bool>> del = qe => true; copy = Queryable.Where( copy, del ); but the `.ElementType` call throws an error because copy is now `EnumerableQuery` rather than `IQueryable`.

Comment: @DCShannon: What is the error exactly, and is this at compile time or execution time? The syntax I'm using for Where is just normal static method syntax, not using the fact that it's an extension method.

Comment: I was referring more to the use of a dynamic variable than the Where call itself, sorry. The error is at execution time. Copied directly from the console window: Unhandled Exception: Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException: 'Sys
tem.Linq.EnumerableQuery<IQueryableWhereTypeChange.ChildQueryElement>' does not
contain a definition for 'ElementType'
   at CallSite.Target(Closure , CallSite , Object )
   at System.Dynamic.UpdateDelegates.UpdateAndExecute1[T0,TRet](CallSite site, T
0 arg0)
   at IQueryableWhereTypeChange.Program.Main(String[] args)

Comment: @DCShannon: Okay, it's probably implementing `ElementType` explicitly. You can use: `var type = ((IQueryable) copy).ElementType;`

Comment: Duh, I should've thought of that. It now compiles and runs, but the output to the console is the same. `copyType2` and `elementType2` are both `ParentQueryElement`. It's getting late and I'm heading home. Thanks again for the help, for now.

Comment: @DCShannon: If you can come up with a short but *complete* example so we can reproduce this, I'll see what I can dig up.

Comment: I'm not sure what else you want me to add to the example to make it complete. I guess I'll add to the question the new code I wrote after your suggestion.

Comment: @DCShannon: A complete example would be something I could copy into a new text file, compile, and run. What you've got looks good - I haven't tried it yet. Sorry if it was already complete before - I must have been too tired :(

Comment: @DCShannon: I've changed the code at the bottom of my answer. With that in place, everything reports `ChildElementType`.

Comment: There we go. I could probably pass in a delegate to the function, although that's going to be a bit of a hassle. I can get the ChildQueryElement type from the passed in IQueryable before making the copy call, so if I can dynamically create the expression based on that type, it should work. Here's a [new question to that effect](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25793736/how-do-i-create-an-expressionfunc-with-type-parameters-from-a-type-variable).

Answer (score 0):

If you know for certain that the elements in the query are going to be of type `ChildQueryElement`, maybe you could simply use the `Cast` method?

```
copy = copy.Where(qe1 => true); // IQueryable<ParentQueryElement>
var copyCasted = copy.Cast<ChildQueryElement>(); // IQueryable<ChildQueryElement>
```

Comment: If I knew for certain the elements were going to be that *particular* subclass, then I would definitely do that. However, the code that prompted this question is set up to handle a number of different child classes, all inheriting from ParentQueryElement.